# Espresso android testing

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

How do I start my test in a specific activity? Say I'm testing a favorites tab in my app, but I'd like my test to start on the login screen, what method would I use to do that? I can't find anything about it anywhere and I'm sure it's just a simple call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide the activity you want to launch first into ActivityTestRule, then login, navigate to the Favorites and tests it:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class TestFavorites {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule(LoginActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        //your setUp
    }

    @Test
    public void testSaveOtherContactToPhoneContacts() {
        logInUser(); //do the login
        //navigate to the favorites tab and test it
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        //your tearDown
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Idly you should test a single activity in the instrumentation tests. If you wish to test the whole flow then go for [automation testing using calabash](http://www.singhajit.com/cucumber-and-calabash-for-android-app-testing/).
In instrumentation test you can test a single activity with different datasets and it will be much faster.

Still if you want to test the whole flow in instrumentation then you can provide the activity in the `ActivityTestRule`.